# Mapping from file.cpp to file.o cmake

Tags: c++, regex, makefile, wildcard

I have a sample `.mk` file like this:

```
CPP_SRCS += \
<FILE_PATH_HERE>/file1.cpp \
<FILE_PATH_HERE>/file2.cpp 

OBJS += \
<FILE_PATH_HERE>/file1.o \
<FILE_PATH_HERE>/file2.o 

CPP_DEPS += \
<FILE_PATH_HERE>/file1.d \
<FILE_PATH_HERE>/file2.d 

<FILE_PATH_HERE>/%.o: <FILE_PATH_HERE>/%.cpp
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler'
    g++ -std=c++11 -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

Suppose that I have many files like `file1.cpp` : `file99.cpp`. Now, it doesn't make sense to manually add corresponding `file1.o` : `file99.o` and `file1.d` : `file99.d` in my `.mk` file.

**My question:** is there a more smart way way to map `.cpp` files to both `.d` and `.o` ?

Comment: `$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(CPP_SRCS))`

Comment: What if I have different paths for `.cpp` and `.o`. In this case, I will need to map <Path1>%.cpp to <Path2>%.o .. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: OK, I got an idea an I will write the full answer

Comment: `$(addprefix my_new_dir/, $(notdir $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)))`

Comment: Just add to your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `.cpp` file list the following should work:

```
CPP_SRCS := \
$(wildcard <CPP_FILES_PATH_HERE>/*.cpp)
```

As per the comment of [liliscent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8605791/liliscent), the following should do the job for `.o` and `.d` files:

```
OBJS := \
$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(CPP_SRCS))

CPP_DEPS := \
$(patsubst %.cpp, %.d, $(CPP_SRCS))
```

However, this works as long as you want `.cpp`, `.o` and `.d` files to be in the same directory. If they should have different directories, you have two solutions:

## First solution:

I recommend using this solution when the paths of `.cpp`, `.o` and `.d` files have a common prefix:

```
OBJS := \
$(subst <CPP_FILES_PATH_HERE>,<O_FILES_PATH_HERE>, $(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(CPP_SRCS)))

CPP_DEPS := \
$(subst <CPP_FILES_PATH_HERE>,<D_FILES_PATH_HERE>, $(patsubst %.cpp, %.d, $(CPP_SRCS)))
```

## Second solution:

I recommend using this solution when the paths of `.cpp`, `.o` and `.d` files are completely different:

```
OBJS := \
$(addprefix <O_FILES_PATH_HERE>, $(notdir $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)))

CPP_DEPS := \
$(addprefix <D_FILES_PATH_HERE>, $(notdir $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.d)))
```